# Linear system solution with fractions in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, fractions

I have matrix `A` and a right-hand-side vector `y` expressed in terms of `fractions.Fraction` objects:

```
import random, fractions, numpy as np

A = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=fractions.Fraction)
y = np.zeros((3, 1), dtype=fractions.Fraction)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i, j] = fractions.Fraction(np.random.randint(0, 4), np.random.randint(1, 6))
    y[i] = fractions.Fraction(np.random.randint(0, 4), np.random.randint(1, 6))
```

I would like to solve the system `A*x = y` using the provided functions in `numpy` and get a result expressed in fraction objects, but unfortunately the basic `x = np.linalg.solve(A, y)` returns the result in standard floating point values:

```
>>> np.linalg.solve(A, y)

array([[-1.5245283 ],
       [ 2.36603774],
       [ 0.56352201]])
```

Is there a way of getting the exact result with fraction objects?

---

EDIT

What I would like to do is just not feasible with the built-in functionalities of numpy (as of version 1.10 - see Mad Physicist's answer). What one could do is implementing his/her own linear solver based on Gauss elimination, which relies on sum, subtraction, multiplication and division, all of which are well-defined and executed exactly with fraction objects (as long as the numerators and denominators fit in the data type, which I think is arbitrarily long).

If you are really interested in having this, just implement a solver yourself, it will be easy and fast to do (follow one of the many tutorials online). I'm not that much interested, so I will stick to the floating point result.

Comment: Is your matrix always 3x3 or is that just incidental? If it is always 3x3, you can code up the matrix inverse by hand in the worst case.

Comment: I actually get an error when I try to run the line `np.linalg.solve(A, y)`. How did you get it to work? Numpy gives the following error: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc solve`. I tried similar code in scipy and it gives `ValueError: object arrays are not supported`.

Comment: The matrix is small, but its size is variable. Say not larger than 10x10. I also know fur sure it is non-singular.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4.3, with numpy 1.9.2 and the code above works just fine.

Comment: I tried Python 3.5.0, Python 2.7.10, with numpy 1.10.1 and scipy 0.16.1 on both. Same error every time. Perhaps the upgrades borked the casting?

Comment: I put it on ideone: http://ideone.com/u1ix7H. It works there as well as on my computer. Unfortunately I cannot do an upgrade to py3.5 or to a newer version of numpy right now. I would not know if what you see is a regression (in case what I'm doing is legal), or my code is illegal and there are new checks in the newer version of the software (or the implementation became incompatible with my illegal stuff).

Comment: I based my answer on things other than my personal setup, which is likely to just be wrong. My numpy is probably set up not to do automatic casting under the hood or something weird like that. The answer should be valid regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible to invert a matrix of rationals using pure numpy according to [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-November/593033.html) on the python mailing list. [The response](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-November/593041.html) suggests that you can use sympy for matrices of rationals up to size 4x4. If you are tied to numpy for some reason, you can consider taking and using the inverse of a 3x3 matrix "manually". Step by step tutorials on how to do this can be found on http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-minors-cofactors-adjugate.html, as well as a large multitude of other tutorials on matrix inversion.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there is no hope. A solution that work in many cases :

```
y = np.zeros(3, dtype=fractions.Fraction)
....
X= np.linalg.solve(A,y)
s=[fractions.Fraction.from_float(x).limit_denominator(6**9) for x in X]
print(s,y==dot(A,s))
```

It uses the property that the solution is nearly a fraction with little numerator and denominator, and find it.

Comment: Well, actually from size of the system and the actual denominators you can analytically find the maximum denominator of the results and use it instead of 6**9. But I think the best way is still to implement a LU decomposition and back-forward substitution yourself if you need that. But yes, after reading the referencces posted by Mad Physicist, I agree that there is no hope in doing everything with the numpy built-in solver.

Comment: it's not elegant but it worked great for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even easier than Gauss elimination, you can implement your own solver based on Cramer's rule.

```
import numpy as np
import fractions

def solve_in_rationals(A: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
    d = int(np.rint(np.det(A)))
    sol = []
    for i in range(np.shape(A)[0]):
        Ai = np.copy(A)
        Ai[:, i] = b
        sol.append(fractions.Fraction(int(np.rint(np.det(Ai))), d))
    return sol
```